# Fast deleting my answer

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-answers

I wanted to post my progress of my code to an already answered question.

So I did it but as an ***answer***, then I realized, and as I noticed from other post/questions that when you want to add something, you edit your question with. Then ADD the things your want whether its the *answer* or More *information*.

Τo be more helpful to other people I deleted my **answer** in **seconds** and edited my question telling that with the help of 2 guys I did that and that.

Questions:

1. My deleted answer is pink and I do not want other people to see that I did a sloppy job. Can others see my deleted answer?
2. Can I make this deleted answer to be not shown to me at all? Or others?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313581/search-by-date-created-the-students-laravel) is the question.

Comment: Only moderators, the owner and people with more than 10k of reputation can see deleted answers like your answer is

Comment: 10k users can [see deleted posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), but generally noone really cares what the quality of a deleted post is like

Comment: try opening this question when you are not logged in (or use incognito / private mode of your browser). That's how 99,99% readers will see it. You'll notice that you can't see deleted answer. See also: [How does deleting work...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/165773)

Comment: I've rolled back your changes to the question. Adding "Edit: SOLVED" to the question, along with an answer, is *not* how this site works. You had it right the first time; if you have an answer to your question, it must be posted *as an answer*, not edited into the question.

Comment: Thank you a lot about answering so fast !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, this part is not correct (emphasis added):

> Then ADD the things your want **whether its the answer** or More information

You should only edit your question to add information or make corrections *to the question*. If you have an answer (even to your own question), it should be posted *as an answer*.

To answer your question, only users with 10k reputation and up can see your deleted answers. They're always posted below other answers though, so people have to scroll down to see them.

Also, nobody really cares about the quality of deleted content, so we generally won't judge you by it. If you *really* want to obfuscate it, you could always edit it to remove whatever it is you're worried about people seeing.

Comment: ["active" sort order doesn't put deleted answers at bottom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231830/165773). Nor does "oldest". I just tested on a site where I have 10K, only sorting by "votes" does this

Comment: Thank you for asnwering that